# Отсортировать массив по типу

Tags: php, массивы, foreach, while

Дано:

Один массив:

```
$arr = array(
    'article',
    'article',
    'video',
    'article',
    'article',
    'article',
    'video',
    'video'
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){

    echo $arr[$i] . '<br>';

}
```

Или два массива:

```
 $arr1 = array(
    'article',
    'article',
    'article',
    'article',
    'article',
);

$arr2 = array(
    'video',
    'video',
    'video'
);

$result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);

for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++){

    echo $result[$i] . '<br>';

}
```

Как провести сортировку этих массивов, в первом или втором примере, чтобы значения в цикле выстраивались следующим образом:

article
video
article
video
article
video
article
article

Где оставшиеся значения которых больше будут идти просто в конце друг за другом?

Comment: [оно?](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e3af30ee747e89ddf51d9625c155f358dd5132c)

Comment: @UserName поменяйте `$first` с `$second` - и код станет нерабочим.

Comment: @lolbas, поменять где?

Comment: получается если 2й массив длиннее в данном примере, код становится нерабочим, думаю вот что lolbas имел ввиду

Comment: @user3193246
Да, есть такое. Не усмотрел. Нужно было еще одну проверку добавить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Унифицированного варианта, который бы работал для двух типов условий, нет. Для второго случая все достаточно просто.

Нужен цикл `for`, количество итераций которого должно быть равно максимальному размеру одного из двух массивов. Далее нужно последовательно добавлять в результативный массив значения исходных, предварительно проверяя, не выйдем ли мы за границы оных.

Пример кода:

```
$arr1 = array(
    'article',
    'article',
    'article',
    'article',
    'article',
);

$arr2 = array(
    'video',
    'video',
    'video'
);

$sorted = array();
$size = array();
$size['arr1'] = count($arr1);
$size['arr2'] = count($arr2);


for ($i=0; $i<max($size['arr1'], $size['arr2']); $i++) {
    if ($i < $size['arr1'])
        $sorted[] = $arr1[$i];
    if ($i < $size['arr2'])
        $sorted[] = $arr2[$i];
}

var_dump($sorted);
```

В результате получим:

```
array(8) {
    [0] => string(7) "article"
    [1] => string(5) "video"
    [2] => string(7) "article"
    [3] => string(5) "video"
    [4] => string(7) "article"
    [5] => string(5) "video"
    [6] => string(7) "article"
    [7] => string(7) "article"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

так, для себя. Пусть у нас есть массив, неважно сколько там значений и сколько из них разных

```
// Узнаем все присутствующие значения
$v = array_count_values($a); 
// отсортируем в порядке возрастания
asort($v);
$res = array();
$prevKey = 0;
while(count($v)) {
   // На сколько след. ключ больше предыдущего
   $i = current($v) - $prevKey;
   // Сохраним текущий счетчик
   $prevKey = current($v);
   // судя по вопросу, первыми должны идти те, что встречаются чаще
   $keys = array_reverse(array_keys($v));
   // Добавим в результат 
   while($i--) 
       $res = array_merge($res, $keys);
   // Текущее значение вставлено убираем его
   array_shift($v);
}
print_r($res);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/578666)